# Categorical Koszul Duality as a form of geometric Langlands

Tags: rt.representation-theory, reference-request

I hope this question is not too unspecific:

Can  Soergel's Categorical Local Langlands conjectures [1]
be interpreted as special form of geometric Langlands.

I think this is somehow hidden in the work Nadler and Benzvi ([2] for example), however i would like to know if there is direct way to see such a connection.

[1] Soergel, Wolfgang;  Langlands' Philosophy and Koszul Duality , Proceedings of NATO ASI 2000 in Constanta, Algebra-Representation Theory, Roggenkamp and Stefanescu (eds.), Kluwer 2001

[2] Benzvi, David; Nadler, David;  Loop Spaces and Langlands Parameters arXiv:0706.0322

Comment: Could you tell us what the conjectures are?

Comment: Yes, at least roughly: 

Soergel conjectures that the category of smooth admissible representations of a real reductive group $G$ can be described by the equivariant derived category of the so-called Adams-Barbasch-Vogan parameter space (equivariant with respect to some action of the Langlands-dual group of the complexification of $G$)

Ok, this has nothing to do with geometric Langlands  on first sight, but he also mentions that similar conjectures should hold in the $l$-adic case.
